# How to force CloudFront cache in all locations

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

I know that CloudFront cache data in edge locations after first "miss" but is there a way to avoid that first miss by forcefully caching my content to all edge servers..?

Even if not an official AWS solution, any nice work-around would do. My current strategy is usually browsing content through VPN, but it's not very easy.

Comment: Why is this necessary?  Obviously, you'd have a somewhat faster response time for subsequent requests, but unless your site has very little traffic, those occasional misses should be of limited consequence. Is this masking a different problem? Is your content a long distance from your typical viewers?  Would a better solution be to replicate your content with multiple origins, globally, and then have CloudFront fetch the content from an origin nearer the viewer?

Comment: Yes, being a small startup, I don't want to give a bad experience to even a single user. CloudFront is an easy-to-implement and cost-effective solution to cater my worldwide users but I use it for dynamically generated content, soothes missed hits become many over the course of time which isn't ideal at this stage when I have only a few users regularizing accessing the new content